# Select records that don't have relation in other tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables:

[image]

where the primary key for each table is its name + id (for example: `UserRole.UserRoleId` is the primary key for `UserRole`, `UserRole.RoleId` and the foreign key of `Role` in `UserRole`).

So I want to select all `Funcionality` without `Profil` (Funcionality.ProfileFuncionality.Count = 0), which I did with the following query :

`SELECT * FROM Funcionality WHERE FuncionalityId NOT IN (SELECT FuncionalityId FROM ProfileFuncionality);`

But I couldn't figure out how to do the following selections :

**All `Funcionality` without `Role` :**

```
Funcionality.ProfileFuncionality.Count > 0 
AND Funcionality.ProfileFuncionality.Profile.RoleProfile.Count = 0
```

**All `Funcionality` without `User` :**

```
Funcionality.ProfileFuncionality.Count > 0 
AND Funcionality.ProfileFuncionality.Profile. RoleProfile.Count > 0
AND Funcionality.ProfileFuncionality.Profile.RoleProfile.Role.UserRole.Count = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expand your sub selects:

So for the **All functionality without a Role:**

```
SELECT *
FROM Funcionality
WHERE FuncionalityId NOT IN
   (SELECT FuncionalityId
    FROM ProfileFuncionality
    JOIN Profile 
        ON Profile.Profileid = ProfileFuncionality.Profileid
    JOIN RoleProfile 
        ON Profile.Profileid = RoleProfile.Profileid);
```

for the **All Funcionality without User :**

```
SELECT *
FROM Funcionality
WHERE FuncionalityId NOT IN
    (SELECT FuncionalityId
     FROM ProfileFuncionality
     JOIN Profile 
        ON Profile.Profileid = ProfileFuncionality.Profileid
     JOIN RoleProfile 
        ON Profile.Profileid = RoleProfile.Profileid
     JOIN Role 
        ON Role.Roleid = RoleProfile.Roleid
     JOIN UserRole 
        ON Role.Roleid = UserRole.Roleid)
 MINUS
 SELECT *
 FROM Funcionality WHERE FuncionalityId NOT IN
     (SELECT FuncionalityId
      FROM ProfileFuncionality
      JOIN Profile 
         ON Profile.Profileid = ProfileFuncionality.Profileid
      JOIN RoleProfile 
         ON Profile.Profileid = RoleProfile.Profileid);
```

I use the minus to subtract the functionality without a role occurrences, since they will obviously also not have a User

Comment: Thank you, it worked, just for the first query u forgot to add this : `AND FONCTIONNALITEID  IN (SELECT distinct FONCTIONNALITEID FROM PROFILFONCTIONNALITE);`, I have updated your answer